# neoclipse connection error: org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RestResultException: Parentheses are required to identify nodes in patterns,

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neoclipse

neo4j version:  Neo4j Desktop -1.1.20

neoclipse version: 1.9.5

[image: Error Details]

The error occurs whenever I start/connect database.

But rightclick on the connection => "ExportToJson" works, and results in the follwing data: `[{"relation":[],"id":72,"propertyMap":{"name":"USA"}},{"relation":[{"endNodeId":130,"relationshipType":"member_of","id":66,"propertyMap":{}}],"id":73,"propertyMap":{"name":"France"}},{"relation":[{"endNodeId":130,"relationshipType":"member_of","id":46,"propertyMap":{}}],"id":74,"propertyMap":{"name":"UK"}},{"relation":[],"id":76,"propertyMap":{"name":"Vatican"}},{"relation":[{"endNodeId":130,"relationshipType":"member_of","id":26,"propertyMap":{}}],"id":94,"propertyMap":{"name":"Italy"}},{"relation":[{"endNodeId":94,"relationshipType":"lies_in","id":24,"propertyMap":{}}],"id":128,"propertyMap":{"name":"Rome","age":"2700 years"}},{"relation":[{"endNodeId":94,"relationshipType":"region_of","id":25,"propertyMap":{}}],"id":129,"propertyMap":{"name":"sicily"}},{"relation":[],"id":130,"propertyMap":{"name":"EU"}},{"relation":[{"endNodeId":129,"relationshipType":"lies_in","id":86,"propertyMap":{}}],"id":150,"propertyMap":{"name":"Palermo"}},{"relation":[],"id":151,"propertyMap":{"name":"moskau"}}]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to tell you,

Neoclipse has been sunset for many years.

Thanks for trying it, but check out "Neo4j Browser" which comes with Desktop.

Where did you find the reference?